# Error: Unknown property 'API.Session_ID' referenced in Links

Tags: visualforce, api, merge-field

I'm trying to move a link from a home page link into a Visual Force Page, but I'm getting this error:

Error Error: Unknown property 'API.Session_ID' referenced in Links

Here's the format of the link that works from the home page, just not on VF page:

```
<a href='https://composer.congamerge.com?sessionId={!API.Session_ID}&serverUrl={!API.Partner_Server_URL_290}&id={!$User.Id}&reportId=00Od0000004ORCh&TemplateId=a0Dd000000c3cyQ&SCHP=2'>Daily F2F TY Postcard - Contact (PR)</a><br/>
```

Anyone see something  wrong in the syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `API` is actually `$Api`. Note that this variable *is case sensitive, and must have the $*.

Comment: Thanks!  I figured it had to be something simple I was missing :)